# Draw pixel per pixel in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview

I'm trying to create a simple software rendering engine. Therefore I'm looking for the most performant way to draw a `UIView` pixel by pixel.

This is what I've tried:

- Draw using `drawRect:`
- Create a `CGContext` using `CGBitmapContextCreate` and draw to it manually

Both of those gave me terrible frame rates, around 15 fps.

Does anybody know a way to draw pixel per pixel in a more performant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add UIImageView as subview of your view and set image property of it with  rendered image outside of drawRect:

```
- (void)renderImageInRect:(CGRect)rect {
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect);
       //draw...
       UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
              self.imageView.image = image;
       });
       UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   }
}
```

The other solution is using OpenGL ES like in [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)

**Edit:**
Another solution based on CALayer without UIImageView subview.

Just change line of code:

```
self.imageView.image = image;
```

with:

```
self.layer.contents = (id) image.CGImage;
```

Comment: This did improve my frame rate quite a bit (30 fps), OpenGL directly is probably the only thing that will get me better performance. Thanks for your answer.